# typescript class decorator:typescript compiler doesn't recognize abstract methods

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a class decorator in typescript.In the decorator
i want to invoke some methods of the class.In addition i want to constraint
the decorator to only be applied on classes that derived from a specific abstract class.

Here what i tried to do:

```
abstract class BaseValidation {
     public abstract getValidationName():string;
     public abstract validation():boolean
}

function ValidationDecorator() {
    return function <T extends BaseValidation>(target: T) {
        let validationName = target.getValidationName();
    }
}

@ValidationDecorator()
class SomeValidation extends BaseValidation{
    public getValidationName():string{
        return "ValidationName";
    }

    public validation():boolean{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the error that i'm getting:

Argument of type 'typeof SomeValidation' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseValidation'.
  Type 'typeof SomeValidation' is missing the following properties from type 'BaseValidation': getValidationName, validation

[A link to typescript playground that showing the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgNWGQEsATYCIgewDsEBvAWACgFWEAHAVxGNgVEgx4CAOY4IBYmQo0AcsAC2OABQBKAFyCi1EQG5mbDt179w0OIgBuhUuSrU16kJUrIcwaswC+zX02YAZpzU8PYIkrYy1AAiOLCUMBAJavQGCFDinFC0QSFRCAA8ACoIOAAeEDjUJBjYYPg20vYAfMoQwFBiEOoIRaqpLGxuVo12coo4CAC8CO2d4gB0XRFN40pq+oM+TNvMAAIrYzFxCeTJqswoaBgAypRKh-nlldW1uI-2jEwAkKxcPEQ+MtRlF5OsNFodF9vr90plsggAEQfNY4RGbWG7H5-YyAhDWKRHRzOVzuajQ2EZCBZHKEeoY1jbLxAA)

According to the error i understand that 'typeof SomeValidation' passes
to the decorator.

Any idea how can i achieve what i described above?

Thanks!

Comment: A [class decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) acts on the class *constructor*, not on any *instance*.  You can't invoke any instance methods... at best you could call static methods.  Without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve (*why* are you trying to call instance methods... of *which* instance? etc), it's hard to suggest how to fix it.  Good luck!

Comment: In the decorator I want to add all clasess that derived form BaseValidation to a map, that the key of the map is the validationName and the value is the validationFunction.Then on runtime i can invoke a validation base on validationName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a [class decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) is applied to the *constructor* of the class, not to an *instance* of the class.

That is, given a constructor type `Ctor<T>` like

```
type Ctor<T> = {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
    prototype: T
}
```

which is both `new`able and has a `prototype` property, your decorator needs to take a `Ctor<BaseValidation>`, not a `BaseValidation`:

```
function ValidationDecorator() {
  return function<T extends Ctor<BaseValidation>>(target: T) {
    // impl
  }
}
```

As for what you do inside the implementation... well, you will only have access to the constructor, not any instance.  You might be able to call methods on the prototype, assuming that they don't need a fully configured instance to work.  For example, let's assume that you are maintaining a map from the `validationName()` return value to the class constructor (you mentioned "validationFunction" in your comment but I don't see that anywhere; presumably you can adapt this if you need to).  This map can be a plain old object instead of a `Map`, since string keys are what plain old objects do best:

```
const validationMap: { [k: string]: Ctor<BaseValidation> | undefined } = {};
```

Then you could implement `ValidationDecorator()` as:

```
function ValidationDecorator() {
  return function<T extends Ctor<BaseValidation>>(target: T) {
    // assuming that getValidationName is a method defined on the prototype
    validationMap[target.prototype.getValidationName()] = target;
  };
}
```

Again, note that `target.prototype.getValidationName()` will only work if the `getValidationName()` method doesn't require an instance of its class to work.  If it's just returning a constant string and doesn't even look at `this`, then that will be okay:

```
@ValidationDecorator()
class SomeValidation extends BaseValidation {
  public getValidationName(): string {
    return "ValidationName";
  }

  public validation(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}

@ValidationDecorator()
class SomeOtherValidation extends BaseValidation {
  public getValidationName(): string {
    return "OtherValidationName";
  }
  public validation(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And we can verify that it works:

```
Object.keys(validationMap).forEach(k =>
  console.log(k + ": " + (validationMap[k] || { name: "oops" }).name)
);
// ValidationName: SomeValidation
// OtherValidationName: SomeOtherValidation
```

So that looks okay.

---

Of course it's probably a bad idea to rely on calling methods directly on the prototype.  Maybe you can change `getValidationName()` and `validation()` methods to be `static` methods instead of instance methods?  But once I start thinking about that I notice that your example code doesn't really show why you're using classes for this at all instead of just some validation functions:

```
const simplerValidationMap = {
  ValidationName: (thingToValidate: any) => false,
  OtherValidationName: (thingToValidate: any) => false
}
```

(with `any` replaced by whatever types you're actually validating).  Perhaps subclasses of `BaseValidation` have some instance state that they manage as well as methods that depend on such state?  But in that case I don't see how having a map from names to non-instances of the class will help you.  Oh well, I guess that's up to you to figure out.

In any case, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/PTAEEFQFwTwBwKagE4LqgzggdlAltgOagCGoAxgPbYZTICu5UlyAsAFCyKgDCzyAHgAqAPlABeUAG8OoUNgQB3UAAoAdBpIAuUthgBKHUIDcoEKDxQLGeUpIAjADZIS2ACah0lN4wQ2yQrKeyJTMXAhGpuaWoAAWJP7BoaHwSF6IyLCglABm0KmggewAvsYcHA60yCRMFI4JNgBCCQgAaiSOeG4k+NTSQXD0TnjkpPZVNVaECFDtnd292AByJAC2CCqGoFUEhGXscoPDo5V0k6AAbh1dPXjUmzr2lJTOrvvF5ezReTCU9MigADWCBg1lAACt6LRSNs6LsADSgX70CiuUBQlyeeoEbL2cEIWoEWgIEgeXIwgCyJDgHHMHQwlERAElQG5qAByKxYTFXea3agAMXo2CYd2wuhgiliCFQiIZtLATPZqwhUK5-F20GldQaFGoVUY-FAgD4NwDsuxwqDQrLybosqXAdFJQABtQE6HZEAC6Oj4LAEzSwc1tYrEAB90e4EDkCAgPMUJNJSp8csLRX0gwsxQARAksHosTb9A5mMBQEjIaZWPCJS0GpgsIKoKD-cUpkWLYSgBAADygODcNl9ggDbWumeoIhEKjLFZmRn0RbkcjpGAw9FWmqg8SmMwz-OWayQ1Zh6y33lZUZjZPFW7SITCqSCcht4+w9udM8rai8D8Qakre6LCs6ybJ6CafjM+xyEmJSfAAAoB2a5tU-CbBa9SrqAADKlDrIhfQ9n27hNC0+HijIxZHJ0owAWO+7ARsWwesQFFLigMwtqAABEZEMVxUGgB87ADEM1GXHRiwPKATwvCS5FPuxzbIK29IIAJQlCRwCESUhVAoQW+jobqOHrAA8reyBkV2vb9iRgY6X0rGeKJIygLRfJAYeUnMYuS5NpxXHmdKlkOQe6z8UEQmHC5owvvuUkya88nFnI-nKaAOSqepHCaewpl4gSUBqMCMAYCocV2tS+hqDkLAAKI1LEKiAhIIhBLWslqI4lCEM1oAANTcToXEDaoFViu+gJgaG4ZOtgh7Dc8cAYCNxTVfN6yGew+j7OYvELdhuGjh5YoKqAQUyvt6w6CZCAXSFJ3UJ8Z32PQVhSqC2ChBa+pcngqxwM4D3BtQ9oJk5V0RKoW67EIlCAVDrgGK1GWqfCQT3ZDOjTrEsPwxJiN6Au4hiJljhYDlQA)